# C# winforms Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I'm trying to read a column from a data reader into a label (c# winform)
My code is as follows:

```
 SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("select  plant_name,plant_id from plant order by plant_id ", connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = command1.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string plantlable = dr.GetInt32("plant_id").ToString();
                labelplantid.Text = plantlable.ToString();

                comboBoxplant.Items.Add(dr["plant_name"]);


            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

I get the error "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' " on the following line

```
string plantlable = dr.GetInt32("plant_id").ToString();
```

with the plant_id underlined in RED.

What am I doing wrong?
I can't seem to figure it out. plant_id is a column type Int. 
Using Sql Server 2008 for the database.

Any hints would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You tried to get integer value from a non-number string, which doesn't make sense. `dr["plant_id"]` should be used instead. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx for `GetInt32` method info.

Comment: thank you.. this worked ....labelplantid.Text= dr["plant_id"].ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SqlDataReader.GetInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method takes an integer as a parameter. That integer marks the index of the field you are trying to reference. In your case, "plant_name" would be index 0 and "plant_id" would be index 1, as that is the order that you specified in the SQL query.

You are getting an error because instead of passing the index, you are treating `GetInt32` as a dictionary getter and trying to access "plant_id" directly. Instead, try the following:

```
string plantlable = dr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
```

Alternatively, you can get the value directly as an object from the SqlDataReader using indexer (array) notation:

```
string plantlable = dr["plant_id"].ToString();
```

Comment: thankyou.. this worked ...
string plantlable = dr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
 labelplantid.Text = plantlable.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

By using this Line `dr.GetInt32("plant_id")` you are trying to read an integer value from the DataReader. and the Error message says that you are trying to convert a string to an Integer, which means that the `plant_id` column will be either a Text or a Varchar or something similar(not an integer) Could you please crosscheck the type?.

If so then you can try [`SqlDataReader.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) method to read that value, in this case you need not to add `.ToString()`, th ecode will be :

```
  labelplantid.Text = dr.GetString("plant_id");
```

Comment: I've looked at the table and here is the create statement.. pretty sure plant_id is int CREATE TABLE [dbo].[plant](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [plant_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [plant_name] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_plant] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: BTW.. using the code you provided still results in the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the answer.. here it is:

```
labelplantid.Text= dr["plant_id"].ToString();
```

or this

```
string plantlable = dr.GetInt32(1).ToString();
labelplantid.Text = plantlable.ToString();
```

either one works. Thanks for the prompt answers :)